# Why is this function to add array inside an array not working?

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, nested

I have created an array. Then I have made call to a function. That function adds another array inside this array. But it is returning an empty array when I `print_r` the main array. Please note that the reason to use `function` is that I intend to call it multiple times.

`PHP`:

```
$myarray = array();
myfunc();
function myfunc() {
    $a = 1;
    $b = "my name";
    $myarray[] = array(
        'a'=>$a,
        'b'=>$b
    );
}
print_r($myarray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have to `return` array from function, capture it to a variable and print that variable.

```
<?php
function myfunc() {
    $myarray[] = array(
        'a'=>1,
        'b'=>"my name"
    );

    return $myarray;
}
$myarray = myfunc();
print_r($myarray);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/7vCmC

***Or you can use*** [Passing by Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
<?php
$myarray = array();
function myfunc(&$myarray) {
    $myarray[] = array(
        'a'=>1,
        'b'=>"my name"
    );
}
myfunc($myarray);
print_r($myarray);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/R9JYL

Note:- variable inside a function has no relation with the same variable outside of it,until it's passed as a reference [2nd answer]. This comes under ***function scope***

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks so much, Passing by Reference (second option) is what I used. I don't know why people are down-voting the question though. :D